Reading x_t parasolid file programatically (preferably in Python)
We are dealing with many x_t parasolid files (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasolid).
We are able to open them in a GUI application, but we are looking for a way to handle them programatically.  We are open to the language choice, but prefer Python due to the members' experience.
It will be great if you could point us to relevant solutions or libraries.
